# RegExp duplicate range in character class

Tags: regex, sonarqube

I'm wondering why `/[\sA-Za-z0-9s#.\',-]/` is marked by my code quality linter as having duplicates?

I know a character class `[abc]` means match one of these, `a, b or c`.

`\s` = whitespace
`A-Z` = match all caps
`a-z` = match all lowercase
`0-9` match all numbers
`s#.\',-` = I really don't know...

Comment: The `s` before `#` is already included in `a-z`.

Comment: Ok @Barmar that's my thought too...perhaps \s was intended, but does \s# do anything? So s#.\' is matching those specific chars `s`, `#`, `.` and `'` ?

Comment: You already have `\s` at the beginning, there's no need to duplicate it.

Comment: Yes, they match those specific characters, just like `[abc]` matches those specific characters.

Comment: Nice -- thanks! I will accept if you add as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate is coming from the `s` in `s#.\',-`, since `s` is included in `a-z`. Just remove it.

```
/[\sA-Za-z0-9#.\',-]/
```

`s#.\',-` matches any of those individual characters. Note that you don't need to escape `'`, unless this is embedded in a programming language string that uses `'` as its delimiters.